# CSS: Horizontal list vertical separators not equally long

Tags: css, html-lists, footer

I'm trying to make a footer for a webpage, using HTML and CSS. I have defined my footer content as an UL with different LIs containing grouped content.

However, I wanted to add seperator in between the content but I can't get them to be equally long because the content differs in vertical lenght and I use border-left. Here's an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P6Fc.jpg

here is my html:

```
<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="centeredfooter">
            <h2 class="Structural">Footer</h2>
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li id="location">
                    <h3>Location</h3>
                    <address>
                        2601 Mission St. San Francisco CA 94110 <BR>
                        Tel: 123.456.7890 <BR>
                        Fax: 123.456.7890 <BR>
                        info@mysite.com
                    </address>
                </li>

                <li id="contact">
                    <h3>Contact</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" title="like us on facebook"><img src="img/Facebook.png" alt="facebook icon" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="follow us on twitter"><img src="img/Twitter.png" alt="twitter icon" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Join us on Google+"><img src="img/Googleplus.png" alt="youtube icon" /></a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>

                <li id="payment">
                    <h3>Payment Methodes</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" title="pay with MasterCard, get info here"><img src="img/mastercard.png" alt="MasterCard icon" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="pay with VISA, get info here"><img src="img/VISA.png" alt="VISA icon" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="pay with PayPal, get info here"><img src="img/PayPal.png" alt="PayPal icon" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="pay with American Express, get info here"><img src="img/AmEx.png" alt="AmEx icon" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
footer {
background-color: #333333;
font-size: 1.4rem;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Palatino Linotype';
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;
text-align: center;
}

#centeredfooter {
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
   margin: 1rem 0;
}

#centeredfooter ul {
clear: left;
float: left;

position: relative;
left: 50%; 
/* By doing a 50% left here, and a 50% right
   in the li we get a nicely centered footer 
   thanks to our #centeredfooter width =100% */
}

#centeredfooter ul li {
display:block;
float:left;

position: relative;
right: 50%;
}

#centeredfooter ul li a {
display: block;
margin: 0.5rem;
}

#location {
padding-right: 1rem;
}

#contact {
border-left: 1px solid #fff;
padding-left: 1rem;
padding-right: 1rem;
}

#payment {
border-left: 1px solid #fff;
padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6PhVD/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll probably get better answers if you post a jsfiddle so we can work with it in real time. The easiest solution to your problem is to use css display:table-cell so that the three divs act like a table and equal the tallest height.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response, I'll keep in mind to add a jsfiddle next time. However, I've tried to add the display:table-cell but it seems I'm doing it wrong because it has no effect, where should I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Apnd/) with the lines going all the way to the bottom. I don't think it's exactly what you need (I removed the horizontal centering so you can actually see the lines), but it should send you in the right direction.

The key is to set `display: table-cell` and remove the `float`.

```css
#centeredfooter ul {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    /*left: 50%;*/
    /* By doing a 50% left here, and a 50% right
       in the li we get a nicely centered footer 
       thanks to our #centeredfooter width =100% */
}
#centeredfooter ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    /*float:left;*/
    position: relative;
    /*right: 50%;*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. The suggestion you made shows no difference for me. I've added a jsfiddle to the question, it does look a bit different though then what I see on my browser when opening the real file.

Comment: That's some fiddle! I've updated the answer with a (mostly) working example. The lines go to the bottom, at least.